# Testing "over the wall" software

Tags: testing

I'm reading a book for certified associate in software testing (CAST) and I'm reading about the challenges of sotware testing; there is a point talk about: Testing "over the wall" software.

what does that means ?

Comment: I've heard of ["throwing it over the wall"](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/throw-it-over-the-wall) for poorly done releases, but not about testing. My best guess is [black-box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing). Or some testing scenario where you have no contact with the developers.

Comment: In China, going "over the wall" means using any kind of proxy server/VPN to bypass the Great Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Business slang for completing your part of a project and then passing it off to the next group. This phrase is usually said when there is little communication between two groups.

Example : Software developers should not simply **throw software over the wall** to test engineers when the developers have finished coding.